# Making getNotificationSettings return instead of using a completion block

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, semaphore

I have a method that is used in several places of an app I'm working on. It's a method to check if remote push notifications are enabled or not. The method returns a value but as you may know `currentUserNotificationSettings` was deprecated so now I'm using `getNotificationSettings`.

The problem is the first returns a value and the latests uses a block. I want to still be able to return a value to avoid refactoring everything so I wrote the following but it's failing and I can't understand why...

Is this ok?!

```
public static var isRemoteEnabled: Bool {
  var notificationSettings: UNNotificationSettings?
  let semasphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 2)

  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { setttings in
      notificationSettings = setttings
      semasphore.signal()
  }

  semasphore.wait()
  guard let authorizationStatus = notificationSettings?.authorizationStatus else { return false }
  return authorizationStatus == .authorized
}
```

**Edited:**

I followed @rmaddy comment and at least now it doesn't crash but it gets stuck in the `wait()`. If I go to debugger and `e semasphore.signal()` it completes and the app continues working fine. Somehow the completion block is not being called.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: did you manage to find out why the completion block is not called?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a case like this you want the semaphore created with an initial value of `0`, not `2`.

```
let semasphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
```

This is mentioned in the documentation:

> Passing zero for the value is useful for when two threads need to reconcile the completion of a particular event.

`wait` first decrements the value. It then blocks until the value is greater or equal to 0. With your value of 2, it was decremented to 1 and since that is already greater or equal to 0, the `wait` didn't need to block and your method returned long before the call to `signal`.

There is also the chance that the completion block for `getNotificationSettings` could be called on the same thread (causing a deadlock) so call it on a background queue.

```
public static var isRemoteEnabled: Bool {
    var notificationSettings: UNNotificationSettings?
    let semasphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {    
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { setttings in
            notificationSettings = setttings
            semasphore.signal()
        }
    }

    semasphore.wait()
    guard let authorizationStatus = notificationSettings?.authorizationStatus else { return false }
    return authorizationStatus == .authorized
}
```

Comment: That was a good advice, but now somehow the completion block is not completed. I just edited my question to add more info. Thanks buddy!

Comment: It's possible that the completion block to `getNotificationSettings` is being called on the same thread which could be causing a deadlock. Wrap it in a call to `DispatchQueue.global().async`.

Comment: Same... the getNotificationSettings is not getting called. This function is used across the whole app and it only fails in one point but I can't identify what's the difference...

Comment: the problem is somewhere else... the method is perfect now but something is weird somewhere else... thanks for your help @rmaddy!